# Select rows with certain combination of conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table of operations similar to one below. `Operations` either succeed or fail. Sometimes, the `operation` is not 'tried', then such a row does not exist:

```
id| Oper. | Success
-------------------
1 |   A   | TRUE
1 |   B   | TRUE
1 |   C   | TRUE
2 |   A   | TRUE
2 |   B   | FALSE
2 |   C   | TRUE
3 |   A   | TRUE
3 |   B   | TRUE
3 |   C   | FALSE
4 |   A   | TRUE
4 |   B   | TRUE
5 |   A   | TRUE
5 |   C   | TRUE
6 |   A   | FALSE
7 |   A   | TRUE
7 |   B   | FALSE
7 |   C   | FALSE
```

How can I find the id's of the rows from table which have either the operation `B` & `C` failed or not tried?

For the example above, the desired result is 2(B failed), 3(C failed), 4(C not tried), 5(B not tried), 6(B & C not tried), 7(both B & C failed)

Comment: Please show your code and indicate where you are having trouble.  The database you are using would help also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. With inspiration from the answers and some coffee my brain started to work and came up with the solution that I cannot believe it was this easy.

The solution, in words, is to `select if not (b & c succeeded)`

The sub-query does the "b & c succeeded" part:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT id FROM table 
   WHERE operation IN('B', 'C') AND success = true
   GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) = 2
)
```

Comment: You can simplify it even furher and avoid subquery: `SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)<2`, but it could fail if (id,oper) is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, because you want rows that are not in the table.

Generate combinations of all ids and operations.  You can do this using a `cross join`.  Then filter out the ones that succeeded:

```
select i.id, op.operation
from (select distinct id from operations) i cross join
     (select distinct operation from operations) op
where not exists (select 1
                  from operations o2
                  where o2.id = i.id and
                        o2.operation = i.operation and
                        o2.success = 'TRUE'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation

```
select id from tbale
group by id
having sum(case when Success='FALSE' then 1 else 0 end)>=1
or count(*)=2
```

when any of the operations will be failed then `sum(case when Success='FALSE' then 1 else 0 end)>=1`this condition will be true and return that id, on the other hand when  3rd operation will not be tried then `count(*)=2` will be true but in case of 2 operations not tried then condtion of will be count(*)<=2

Comment: @CaiusJard its a simple aggregation you can try https://dbfiddle.uk by creating table it will work

Comment: I know how it works; I'm trying to encourage you not just to solve the OP's problem but to explain it (teach) for his benefit and for future visitors.

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks I tried to explain and you are welcome  to add any notes which will help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that operation A is always present:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  CASE  
    WHEN b.Success = 'FALSE' THEN '(B failed)'
    WHEN b.Success IS NULL THEN '(B not tried)'
    WHEN c.Success = 'FALSE' THEN '(C failed)'
    WHEN c.Success IS NULL THEN '(C not tried)'
  END as reason
FROM
  (SELECT id, success FROM table WHERE oper = 'A') A

  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, success FROM table WHERE oper = 'B') B
  ON A.id = B.id

  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, success FROM table WHERE oper = 'C') C
  ON A.id = C.id

WHERE
  'FALSE' in (c.success, b.success) OR b.success is null or c.success is null
```

In essence we break your data in 3 virtual tables and left join them, looking for either the false or the null created by the left join when the data doesn't exist. This also allows us to determine why things went wrong. I wasn't sure whether the words in brackets were actual output you wanted or just you explaining why that number should appear in the results.

I considered funky sum/count solutions like Gordon/Zaynul posted but for me this form is more self documenting/readable. Do check the performance though, as indexing the Oper column may help considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...
Please find this link for more info about `exists` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
  select tab.id, operate.operation from 
  (select distinct id from table) as tab cross join
  (select distinct operation from table ) as operate
  where not exists ( select * from table as table 
  where tab.id=table.id and tab.operate=table.operate and table.success='true' )
```

Comment: ugh, ANSI-89 joins. Please update to ANSI-92, and also explain how it works

Answer (score 0):

A cross join is not required nor supported by all SQL engines, such as MySQL. The first select statement just selects distinct id's where the operation is either 'B' OR 'C' and success is 'FALSE'. But we need to add those id's that either 'B' or 'C' was never attempted. Those would be id's in the table for which there are no values of either 'B' or 'C' in the operation column.

```
/* select all id's that have been tried but failed: */
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM operation
    WHERE operation IN ('B', 'C') AND success = 'FALSE'

UNION

/* select all id's that have never tried 'B': */
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM operation
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM operation
            WHERE operation = 'B'
    )

UNION

/* select all id's that have never tried 'C': */
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM operation
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM operation
            WHERE operation = 'C'
    )
;
```